# How to make simple bots logger for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, logging, bots, code-snippets

to me honest, I am not very experienced coder. But I would like have some **simple bots logger** for Wordpress. All what I need is just to log 'user-agent' name into some basic txt file.

Having date/time is just a bonus.

Does anyone knows some simple php code / snippet which I can put into header.php or functions.php please?

Thank you. Best wishes,

Milan

**UPDATE:**
So solution by Kristopher Ives works perfectly, thank you.

And if I want **put a time and date of the user-agent visit** what I should inset into:

```
add_action('wp', function(){
  file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/useragents.log', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\n", FILE_APPEND);
});
```

How it should look like? I do something wrong with characters , . ; I am confused :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple function, to write something to file:

```
function simpleLogger ($logMsg){
    file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.log', $logMsg, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Wordpress plugin you'll need to hook into every page request and write to a file:

```
add_action('wp', function(){
  file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/useragents.log', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\n", FILE_APPEND);
});
```

However, be aware that many PHP environments don't have write access to files for security reasons, so you will need to `chmod g+w` that file so it's writable by PHP. Also be aware that this information likely already exists in `/var/log/apache/*access.log` as well as many existing Wordpress plugins that will save this information to a database and provide basic reporting functionality for you, such as [WP Statistics](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-statistics/)

Comment: Thank you! It looks interesting. I know that the file should be 775 or 777 if no extra rules will be added (I guess :) )
And now I made SSH connection to my VPS, but for some reasons I cannot see any existing log which should be visible on my side. For example: I have image/disk_1/log/ or /disk_1/home/web/logs/ and it is empty :-/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :)

```
add_action('wp',function () {
$timestamp = date('d/m/Y h:i:s ');
file_put_contents(__DIR__ .'/useragents.log', $timestamp.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\n",FILE_APPEND); }
);
```